# Karma - JUnitReport - ANT: empty report

Tags: ant, junit, angularjs, karma-runner

I have some AngularJS E2E tests that run normally and have reporters set to:

```
...
reporters = ['junit'];
junitReporter = {
    outputFile : 'test/e2e-results.xml',
    suite : 'e2e'
};
...
```

The reports xml file is generated and contains a hierarchy of testsuites->testsuite->testcases....

I'm trying to use ANT to generate HTML reports.

```
<junitreport todir="./reports">
   <fileset dir="./reports">
      <include name="e2e-results.xml"/>
   </fileset>
   <report format="frames" todir="./report/html"/>
</junitreport>
```

The HTML files are generated properly, but all values in the tables are empty, 0 Tests, 0 Failures etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance